# Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property

Tags: zend-framework, php

I'm trying to use some extended `Zend_Db_Table` class from PHP CLI (Command Line Interface).

Everything is working as expected, when used via Apache. But when used from CLI I get the following error:

> [01-Feb-2011 14:41:34] PHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: `KidsclubIdentities::$tableName` in /home/www/

If I `var_dump($tableVariables); die();` in the `col()` function of the class below I get a printout as expected, but **NOT INCLUDING** the `public static` variables of my model (`KidsclubIdentities`).

So my best guess is that the scope is different, when using CLI vs. Apache

```
class My_Db_Table extends Zend_Db_Table
{
    public function col($varname) {
        $tableVariables = get_class_vars(get_class($this));
        if(array_key_exists($varname, $tableVariables)) {
            return $tableVariables[$varname];
        } else if(array_key_exists($varname . 'Column', $tableVariables)) {
            return $tableVariables[$varname . 'Column'];
        }
        return $varname;
    }

[...]
```

My model

```
class KidsclubIdentities extends My_Db_Table
{
    protected $_name = 'kidsclub_identities';
    protected $_rowClass = 'KidsclubIdentity';

    public static $tableName = 'kidsclub_identities';
    public static $primaryColumn = 'kidsclub_identity_id';
    public static $statusColumn = 'kidsclub_identity_status';
    public static $userIdColumn = 'user_id';
    public static $identityIdColumn = 'identity_id';
    public static $identityLocationTypeColumn = 'identity_location_type';
```

I was planning to use CLI to execute some operations from crontab. But I will move my focus onto apache based cron-script.

Comment: In PHP you do not inherit static members. Is there some reason it thinks $tableName is inherited?

Comment: Well.. i'm allready using it with great success, it's only from CLI i have experienced problems.

Comment: And by the way, the static variables are not inherited - nothing extends KidsclubIdentities. The function col() is inherited from My_Db_Table.

Comment: have a look here ( worked without problems for me ) http://webfractor.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/using-zend-framework-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but allready have other ZendFramework 'stuff' working from CLI :)

Comment: I think Apache vs. CLI is misleading here. Are both using the same PHP version and error_reporting settings? Remember that they have separate php.ini files. I'm not exactly sure what your code is meant to do but $this won't exist if you call a method statically.

Comment: Check that the PHP your using in your browser (via Apache) is the same as the PHP your invoking from CLI - if they are different versions then you may have issues?

Comment: Also I just tried a test script and got the same error via. Apache and CLI (undefined variable $this), this is with PHP 5.3.3

Comment: Can you confirm that the line number of the error is in the above extract?

Comment: Same install for PHP, only one .ini, the function i call is not static, i nailed it down to get_class_vars by simple echo/die debugging.

Comment: You do inherit static members in PHP, albeit in a somewhat weird way: the inherited variable in the descendant class will be a reference pointing to the variable of the parent class. (In essence, the parent and the child will share the static variables.)

Comment: I know this doesn't resolve your original problem, but you can also cURL an action inside your application within crontab. You will of course need to add some sort of protection, but usually a hardcoded app id and secret passed via `GET` should do the trick.